# Ошибка с кодированием SHA1

Tags: java, android, sha

Использую в приложении библиотеку `commons-codec-1.10.jar` от Apache.
Есть у меня метод:

```
private static String hashLoginPassword(String user, String password, String sessionAttr) {
    return DigestUtils.sha1Hex(DigestUtils.sha1Hex(user.toLowerCase() + password) + sessionAttr);
}
```

При выполнении, приложение вылетает с ошибкой:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method encodeHexString([B)Ljava/lang/String; in class Lord/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex' appears in /system/framework/ext.jar)
at org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.sha1Hex(DigestUtils.java:438)
```

Искал информацию в интернете. Если я правильно понял, то многие пишут (у кого похожая ситуация), что проблема в том, что неправильно определяется путь. Но мои танцы с бубном не устранили ошибку. Помогите.

Этот же код использую не в `Android Studio`, а в `Intellij Idea (Java SE)` и все работает.

Comment: Использую эту же библиотеку версии 1.6. Проблем не наблюдалось. Вам нужна именно 1.10?

Comment: @Chubatiy Попробовал 1.6 - та же ошибка.

Comment: Посмотрите в зависимости, найдите класс `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex`. И поищите в нем метод `encodeHexString`. Убедитесь, что есть это все в итоговом вашем приложении. Может по каким-то причинам сборщик не включает его или включает, но не ту версию. Попробуйте так же выполнить просто метод `Hex.encodeHexString(byte[] data)`. + Возможное решение https://github.com/figo-connect/java-figo/blob/36d511e19bbfb0600fdfeb842b15a7653cae8333/src/main/java/me/figo/internal/FigoTrustManager.java#L85